# CSS Sidebar Menu Overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I add text for my side navigation bar the text will overflow to the next line instead of just continuing on the same line. For example I want it CRF Notes and CRI Notes not to overflow like the currently are. I am not sure what I am missing. I have tried changing the display to in-line block but that did not work. I messed with certain widths in the CSS page. I am sure I am just over-looking something but cannot figure it out.

[image]

Here is the html for the nav menu

```
         <div class="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block w3-card w3-animate-left" style="display:none" id="mySidebar">
      <button class="close_button"
          onclick="w3_close()">Close</button><br />
        <a href="default.aspx" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Home</a> <br />
        <a href="application.aspx"class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Application</a><br />
        <a href="vehicle.aspx"class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Vehicle</a><br />
        <a href="AddOn.aspx" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">NADA</a><br />
        <a href="visa.aspx"class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Visa</a><br />
        <a href="AppNotes.aspx" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">CRF Notes</a><br />
        <a href="CritNotes.aspx" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">CRI Notes</a><br />

      </div>

    <div id="main">
        <div class="w3-teal">
        <button id="openNav" class="w3-button w3-teal w3-xlarge" onclick="w3_open()">Navigation</button>
        <div class="w3-container">

            </div>
</div>
        </div>
  </nav>
```

here is the script for the open and close button

```
 <script>
         function w3_open() {
             document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "5%";
             document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "5%";
             document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "block";
             document.getElementById("openNav").style.display = "none";

         }
         function w3_close() {
             document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0%";
             document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "none";
             document.getElementById("openNav").style.display = "inline-block";

         }

    </script>
```

and here is my css

```
body{
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #eff6ee;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    height:auto;
    bottom:0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:00px;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
}



#wrapper {
    background-color: white;
    width: auto;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-left: 36px;
}

nav {
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
    padding-top:50px;
    padding-right:55px;
    background-color:#2e3532;
    height:100%;


}

#rightcol {
    margin-left: 100px;
    background-color: #eff6ee;
    color: #000000;
    height:100%;
}


header {
    background-color: #9197ae;
    font-size: 100%;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    padding-top:3px;
}

h1{
    padding-top:10px;
    text-shadow: -2px 0 #f00,0 2px #f00, 2px 0 #f00, 0 -2px #f00;
    color:#eff6ee;
    margin-left:135px
}

h2 {
    color: #869dc7;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;

}

main {
    display:flex;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px;
}

#floatright {
    margin: 10px;
    float: right;
}


nav a {
    margin: 30px;
    color:#9197ae;

}

nav a:visited{
    color:mediumpurple;
}

nav a:hover{
    color:white;
    text-decoration:underline;
}

.close_button{
    width:125px;
    text-align:center
}

#openNav{
    width:125px;
    text-align:center
}



.logo{
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px
}

.ssninput{
    background-color:#eff6ee;
    padding-left:10px
}

.table{
    padding-left:10px
}
```

Comment: Can you link any example with fiddle ?

Comment: Not sure what fiddle is?

Comment: Go [here](https://jsfiddle.net/) past your code with all library/image we need to run live example.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ryans21/rv32wyf8/#&togetherjs=9fADidF21H

Answer (score 0):

In **w3_open()** function,  **document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width** should not be **5%**.
It should be more than **15%**( this value will depend with other css styles.How ever you should increase that width).

```css
body {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #eff6ee;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 00px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}


#wrapper {
    background-color: white;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 36px;
}

nav {
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-right: 55px;
    background-color: #2e3532;
    height: 100%;


}

#rightcol {
    margin-left: 100px;
    background-color: #eff6ee;
    color: #000000;
    height: 100%;
}


header {
    background-color: #9197ae;
    font-size: 100%;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-top: 3px;
}

h1 {
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-shadow: -2px 0 #f00, 0 2px #f00, 2px 0 #f00, 0 -2px #f00;
    color: #eff6ee;
    margin-left: 135px
}

h2 {
    color: #869dc7;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;

}

main {
    display: flex;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px;
}

#floatright {
    margin: 10px;
    float: right;
}


nav a {
    margin: 30px;
    color: #9197ae;

}

nav a:visited {
    color: mediumpurple;
}

nav a:hover {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.close_button {
    width: 125px;
    text-align: center
}

#openNav {
    width: 125px;
    text-align: center
}


.logo {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px
}

.ssninput {
    background-color: #eff6ee;
    padding-left: 10px
}

.table {
    padding-left: 10px
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block w3-card w3-animate-left" style="display:none" id="mySidebar">
    <button class="close_button"
            onclick="w3_close()">Close
    </button>
    <br/>
    <a href="default.aspx" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Home</a> <br/>
    <a href="application.aspx" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Application</a><br/>
    <a href="vehicle.aspx" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Vehicle</a><br/>
    <a href="AddOn.aspx" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">NADA</a><br/>
    <a href="visa.aspx" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Visa</a><br/>
    <a href="AppNotes.aspx" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">CRF Notes</a><br/>
    <a href="CritNotes.aspx" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">CRI Notes</a><br/>

</div>

<div id="main">
    <div class="w3-teal">
        <button id="openNav" class="w3-button w3-teal w3-xlarge" onclick="w3_open()">Navigation</button>
        <div class="w3-container">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>

<script>
function w3_open() {
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "5%";
    document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "15%"; // I updated this one
    document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("openNav").style.display = "none";

}

function w3_close() {
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0%";
    document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("openNav").style.display = "inline-block";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Lakshitha- i updated the width to 15% but it still did not work

Comment: Oh, Try adding more than 15%.

Answer (score 0):

You are giving padding-right to nav element which is narrowing it, and also setting the div width to 5% by js, which should be to 100%.

Hope [This](http://jsfiddle.net/aq7b6m5r/) fiddle helps you.

```
nav {
   float: left;
   width: 150px;
   padding-top:50px;
   /*padding-right:55px;*/
   background-color:#2e3532;
   height:100%;
}


     function w3_open() {
         document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "5%";
         //document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "5%";
         document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "100%";
         document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "block";
         document.getElementById("openNav").style.display = "none";

     }
     function w3_close() {
         document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0%";
         document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "none";
         document.getElementById("openNav").style.display = "inline-block";

     }
```

Comment: I've made those changes but it still isnt working, strangely

Answer (score 0):

i edited this function (change inline block and delete width):

```
function w3_open() {
             document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "5%";
             document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "inline-block";
             document.getElementById("openNav").style.display = "none";

         }
```

It's how you want?

```js
   function w3_open() {
             document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "5%";
             document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "inline-block";
             document.getElementById("openNav").style.display = "none";

         }
         function w3_close() {
             document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0%";
             document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "none";
             document.getElementById("openNav").style.display = "inline-block";

         }
```

```css
body{
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #eff6ee;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    height:auto;
    bottom:0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:00px;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
}



#wrapper {
    background-color: white;
    width: auto;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-left: 36px;
}

nav {
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
    padding-top:50px;
    padding-right:55px;
    background-color:#2e3532;
    height:100%;
    
    
}

#rightcol {
    margin-left: 100px;
    background-color: #eff6ee;
    color: #000000;
    height:100%;
}


header {
    background-color: #9197ae;
    font-size: 100%;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    padding-top:3px;
}

h1{
    padding-top:10px;
    text-shadow: -2px 0 #f00,0 2px #f00, 2px 0 #f00, 0 -2px #f00;
    color:#eff6ee;
    margin-left:135px
}

h2 {
    color: #869dc7;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
   
}

main {
    display:flex;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px;
}

#floatright {
    margin: 10px;
    float: right;
}


nav a {
    margin: 30px;
    color:#9197ae;
  
}

nav a:visited{
    color:mediumpurple;
}

nav a:hover{
    color:white;
    text-decoration:underline;
}

.close_button{
    width:125px;
    text-align:center
}

#openNav{
    width:125px;
    text-align:center
}



.logo{
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px
}

.ssninput{
    background-color:#eff6ee;
    padding-left:10px
}

.table{
    padding-left:10px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href="CSS/StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<title>Home</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

    <nav>
   <div class="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block w3-card w3-animate-left" style="display:none" id="mySidebar">
   <button class="close_button"
    onclick="w3_close()">Close</button><br />
  <a href="default.aspx" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Home</a> <br />
  <a href="application.aspx"class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Application</a><br />
  <a href="vehicle.aspx"class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Vehicle</a><br />
        <a href="AddOn.aspx" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">NADA</a><br />
  <a href="visa.aspx"class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Visa</a><br />
  <a href="AppNotes.aspx" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">CRF Notes</a><br />
  <a href="CritNotes.aspx" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">CRI Notes</a><br />
  
   </div>

 <div id="main">
  <div class="w3-teal">
  <button id="openNav" class="w3-button w3-teal w3-xlarge" onclick="w3_open()">Navigation</button>
  <div class="w3-container">

   </div>
</div>
  </div>
  </nav>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="wrapper">
  
  <div id="rightcol">
 <header>
  <img src="Images/GCSCU_Color.gif" height:"90" width="120" align="left" class="logo"/><h1>CRIF Access</h1>
 </header>
 <main> 
   
 <h5>To begin click on the navigation button on the side.<br />
        <br />
 There you will see a menu with different purposes. The first is the home page. Click on that to get back to this page.<br />
 Second is the application page. Here you will enter the member's AppID and it will bring back details in relation to the original CRIF application.<br />
 The third option is the vehicle page. Enter the vehicle's VIN number and it will bring back details about the vehicle on the loan.<br />
 The forth option will bring back information about a Visa that was opened up via CRIF when you submit the AppID.<br />
 The last page is a summary page that is currently still being worked on. This page can give you overall summary data about loan numbers from certain branches,<br />
 during specific times of a selected year, from a certain dealer..etc.
 </h5>
  
 </main>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: @RyanS can you acept my answer with flag and upvote?